# WiFi issues on 2017 MacBook Air

Tags: wifi, networking, macbook

[image]

So I just installed elementary 5.0 on my MacBook Air (2017), from a Flash Drive, and while the network connection seemed to work perfectly during installation, and while it saved the network info regardless, now that it’s installed and rebooted it doesn’t seem to want to connect to it whatsoever. As you can see from the pic when I open the network settings the connection shows up, and when I open it and go to the general tab the “automatically connect to this network when it is available” is checked off but it doesn’t seem to be actually connecting? Is this a simple driver issue or is there something I’m missing? Cause as I said I’m pretty sure I was connected through the installation process but now all of a sudden it’s just chillen and not really doing anything for me :/

It’s late so if I don’t reply to any posts or questions soon, I’m just sleeping and will reply ASAP in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary requires a driver for most Broadcom WiFi chips, like those in Macbooks. All you have to do is establish a temporary network connection with Ethernet or a USB WiFi adapter and run `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`